# Replace and rearrange string value containing similar pattern of words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

I am working in google collaboratory and I have a panda dataframe like below

```
Company name            Address
Meditera, PT            Street 1
Ocean express, PT       Street 2
```

I want to change to be like below :

```
Company name            Address
PT Meditera            Street 1
PT Ocean express       Street 2
```

The way I do now is using `df['Company name'].str.replace('Meditera, PT','PT Meditera')`. The data is growing each day and it will be so exhaustive to replace one by one. The pattern of the data is the same, I only need to rearrange ', PT' from behind to the front of company name.

Is there any suggestion how we can do this in smarter way so that I do not need to manually use `str.replace()` every day.

Thanks before

Comment: Done @user17242583 I have accept your answer. I'm sitting all day long just to replace company name.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df['Company name'] = df['Company name'].str.split(', ').str[::-1].str.join(' ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Company name   Address
0       PT Meditera  Street 1
1  PT Ocean express  Street 2
```

Comment: wow, let me try it first. But could you explain a little why we use `[::-1]`? For `.str.split()` and `.str.join()' I never read about it but I can try by myself googling it

Comment: I'll answer for him `[::-1]` just invert the order of a list.

Comment: Yes, @Fendy, rpanai is right. Say you have a list `l = [1,2,3,4,5]`. If you `print(l[::-1])` you'll get `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) :)

Comment: I try your solution and it's really works out, all the data of company name already in the right pattern of words. Thanks all. I will vote your comment as the answer.